# Is there any function in postgres to check integrity for table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, db2

There was this sql to check table integrity in db2.
SET INTEGRITY FOR table_name IMMEDIATE CHECKED.

Based on some research, found that it is to check whether there is any violations/constraints in data while saving.
I need to find equivalent one in postgres.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds as if you are looking for deferred constraints. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html

Comment: For Db2 `SET INTEGRITY FOR ... IMMEDIATE CHECKED` brings one or more tables out of set integrity pending state by performing required integrity processing on those tables. See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-set-integrity.

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini I read this about set integrity. I am new to db2 and didnt understand what it meant exactly. Asked few  people around about that and they told like it is used to maintain the order of save data like that.
I need to know exactly what it means before I can try to write it in postgres.

Comment: @Hera, there is nothing similar in postgres (AFAIK). See mustaccios answer below

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an exact equivalent in Postgres, mainly because the `INTEGRITY PENDING` state is not something a Postgres table can have. You can validate individual constraints that were created with the `NOT VALID` option using `ALTER TABLE ... VALIDATE CONSTRAINT`.

[Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-NOTES).

Comment: Instead of trying to blindly mimic Db2 code on Postgres, you should understand its _intent_ and use the appropriate native Postgres feature, if necessary.